# How to start a service upon an lxc container start?

Tags: startup, services, lxc

I would like to start OpenVPN automatically upon the launch of its `lcx` container.

The container runs Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS, `service openvpn start` is successful (when launched from the running container) and it looks like it is enabled for autostart:

```
root@vpn:~# update-rc.d openvpn defaults
 System start/stop links for /etc/init.d/openvpn already exist.
```

The `openvpn` service is not, however, started when doing a `lxc vpn restart` (the container itself starts fine, and I can launch `openvpn` manually afterwards).

**What else should be done to automatically start a service upon the launch of an `lxc` container?**